# Json not serializing all object in Azure

Tags: c#, json, azure, serialization

I have POCO which is as simple as

```
public partial class Member
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string MemberId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }}
```

and a Add command which looks like this

```
   public class AddMemberCommand : ICommand
{
    public AddMemberCommand(Member member  )
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        MemberData = member;
    }


    public  Member MemberData { get; private set; }

    public Guid ID { get; }


    public string CommandName
    {
        get { return "AddMemberCommand"; }

    }
}
```

which inherits from

```
public interface ICommand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the command identifier.
    /// </summary>
    Guid ID { get; }

    string CommandName { get; }
}
```

Now I send this code to a method which initializes Newton Json's serializing setting class with some parameters to return an object. The serializer looks like this

```
    public class JsonTextSerializer 
{
    private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;

    public JsonTextSerializer()
    {
        _serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
        });
    }

    public void Serialize(TextWriter writer, object graph)
    {
        var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
        jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        _serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, graph);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    public object Deserialize(TextReader reader)
    {
        var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);

        try
        {
            return this._serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader);
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException e)
        {
            // Wrap in a standard .NET exception.
            throw new SerializationException(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
}
```

The serializer is used to convert the command into a payload for the brokered message as shown below

```
        private BrokeredMessage CreateMessage(POCOS.Member member)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonTextSerializer();
        var command = new AddMemberCommand(member);
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, command);
        stream.Position = 0;
        BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(stream, true);
        return message;

    }
```

and there is a another method which receives the method

```
   private POCOS.Member GetPocoFromMessage(BrokeredMessage message)
    {
        ITextSerializer serializer = new JsonTextSerializer();
        AddMemberCommand command;

        using (var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var payload = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                command = payload as AddMemberCommand;
            }
        }

        return command.MemberData;
    }
```

The issue is on deserializing some properties ( ***ID, CommandName***) are filled with value except for  ***MemberData*** which is null. 
I can read the stream (by doing a reader.ReadToEnd()) and see it was transferred over the wire but Json can't  deserialize all its object
At one time I also thought it perhaps picks only fields in the Interface but that's not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MemberData` property has a private setter.  Since the serializer needs access to the property externally, this setter should be public.